# Pox virus infection process

Tags: microbiology, virology, infection

How does Pox virus duplicate it's genome? Does it bring DNA polymerase or RNA polymerase into the host cell?

Answer (score 3):

Poxviruses, such as [variola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallpox) (the causative agent of smallpox) and [vaccinia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccinia) (the active constituent of the vaccine that eradicated smallpox), are very large, complex DNA viruses that replicate in the cytoplasm, rather than the nucleus. Because of this, they must carry enzymes with them to accomplish tasks that occur in the nucleus of the eukaryotic cells they infect. This includes all the proteins necessary for mRNA synthesis (e.g., a DNA dependent RNA polymerase). The enzymes for DNA replication are encoded in the poxvirus genome and are transcribed and translated as part of the "early" stage, directly after adsorption and penetration.

So, **yes, poxviruses bring their own preformed RNA polymerase with them**. They don't bring their own DNA polymerase with them, but they do produce it shortly after infecting a cell.

You can read more about this in Murray Medical Microbiology Chapter 54.